# saving image(url format ) from api in sqlite local datbase but don't know how

Tags: flutter

i have api which have images in url ,i want to save that image in sqlite local database for cart page purpose in my flutter app ,i did some search on google by that i found to convert in image to base 64 which will convert the image to string but that like in png or jpeg or that format but i have my images from api url. i dn't know how to do it any help will be appreciated

```
 "images": [
        "https://west-1.amazonaws.com/images/full/5bc9839886fc106413b9407f42ed776b9b7bd9.jpg",

    ],
```

i have images like this

Answer (score 0):

Add the http package:

```
http: ^0.12.0+2
```

Imports:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
```

Download the image and base64 encode:

```
// Substitute your image URL
String uri = 'https://pub.dev/static/img/pub-dev-logo-2x.png?hash=umitaheu8hl7gd3mineshk2koqfngugi';

http.Request request = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse(uri));

http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse = await request.send();

http.Response response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

if(response.statusCode != 200) {
  throw Exception("Couldn't get data becuase of ${response.statusCode}");
}

String data = base64.encode(response.bodyBytes);
```